# Why is NSTableView not reloading?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm still very new to programming in Swift, (and never with Objective C). What I'm trying to do is add to the NSTableView when I've clicked on an item in the current tableview. The items seem to be adding when clicked, but the table does not seem to be refreshing with the new things in the array.

I've tried various things over the last few days, getting it to run reloadData on main thread and UI thread, etc but I'm feel like I'm just hitting the wall (it surely can't be this hard to do something so simple like I can in a couple minutes in Java)....

Have I missed something very obvious? (Code below)

```
class TableViewController: NSTableView, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

var items: [String] = ["Eggs", "Milk"]


func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    let result : TableCell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as! TableCell

    result.itemField.stringValue = items[row]

    return result

}


func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    let index = notification.object!.selectedRow

    if (index != -1) {
        NSLog("@%d", index)
        items.append("Blah")
        NSLog("@%d", items.count)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.reloadData()
        })

    }
}

func relloadData() {     //relload is not a typo
    self.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: is it intentional that your class **is** the tableview? and what is the purpose of `relloadData`?

Comment: Yes (that's the way I'e been following it in tutorials unless it's not best practice which I am not aware of).The purpose of relload data is for debugging purposes.

Comment: Are main thread and UI thread two threads? Are the items added?

Comment: As per my problem description items seem to be added as the size of the array is incrementing with each click. I believe they run on the same thread, but I updating them in either of the main or UI thread still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a UI thread which isn't the main thread? Which methods of NSTableView did you override?

Comment: Generally, the controller should not be the same object as the table view. Also, you need to explain how your UI was set up. Did you use a NIB? A storyboard? Or did you set things up programmatically? If a NIB or storyboard, does it have both a table view of your custom class in the view hierarchy and also an instance of your controller class (which is currently the same class) as a separate object outside of the view hierarchy? How are the delegate and data source of the table view connected?

Answer (score -1):

If you're binding your user interface to the `items` property of your view controller subclass, you need to mark it as it a Dynamic Variable:

```
dynamic var items: [String] = ["Eggs", "Milk"]
```

Place the `dynamic` keyword before the property declaration and I think it will solve your problem.

Note that Ken's comment also makes a good point in that this code probably should be written as an NSViewController subclass, instead of a subclass of NSTableView.

If you're using Storyboards, the custom view controller subclass would be a View Controller object for the view containing your table view. If you're using a xib file for the view, the view controller subclass would be the File's Owner. In either case, you would connect the table view's delegate and data source outlets to that object.

Comment: This would be the answer with bindings. The question is about a datasource which doesn't use KVO.